# Joomla database tables have duplicates that start with bak_

Tags: database, phpmyadmin

I have a Joomla website, and somehow, the database shows duplicate entries for every table row. The duplicates all start with bak_. I assume it was caused by some sort of backup process, but this has never happened with any of my other Joomla sites. I always just export the database periodically to perform backups.

Stupid question, but is it safe to simply drop all the bak_ tables? Will my website be unaffected? I assume so, but I want to be sure.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/352329

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need to worry about these tables. They are generated from the Akeeba Backup extension when you perform a backup.

You can drop these table and no, your site **won't** be affected.

Comment: @Kris If you are satisfied with this answer, please award it the big green tick so that your question is deemed "resolved" in the system (and Lodder is compensated for his insight).  Please always endeavor to progress your questions toward a resolution for the benefit of this community.  Please edit your previous question to clarify what remains unsolved and/or comment to Lodder to try and work out the issue.  Even if you are no longer seeking a solution for that question, Joomla researchers will benefit from knowing if the issue is sufficiently resolved or not.